# List type mismatch when appending in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Let's say I have following code:

```
val xs: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
val ys: List[Int] = List(4, 5, 6)
val zs: List[Int] = xs.appended(ys)
```

The last line does not compile with an error:

> Error:(162, 33) type mismatch; found   : List[Int] required: Int val
>   zs: List[Int] = xs.appended(ys)

If I remove the explicit type declaration, then the code compiles, but the real problem is that
the error message appears in a recursive function where I would like to pass appended list as a parameter of type `List[Int]`, so removing the explicit type is not an option.

Comment: element of the list is integer but you are trying to insert List[Int] hence you are getting type miss match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [scaladoc](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#:+[B%3E:A](elem:B):CC[B]) `appended` method takes only one argument, not an entire list. So the following examples will compile:

```
xs.appended(ys(0))
for(x <- xs) yield ys appended x
```

or `appendAll`:

```
xs appendAll ys
ys :++ xs
```

P.S.: Note, that appending to the list is not optimal, as it's time is proportional to the size of the list, prefer prepend instead:

```
ys ::: xs
```

Answer (score 2):

According [scala documentation](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html) `appended` method accepting just one element, not collection. And zs type after removing explicit types will be `List[Any]`:

```
val xs = List(1, 2, 3)
val ys = List(4, 5, 6)
val zs: List[Any] = xs.appended(ys) // List(1, 2, 3, List(4, 5, 6))
```

it compiles, but result will be `List(1, 2, 3, List(4, 5, 6))`

You can use method `appendedAll` to do that you want or just concatenate lists using `concat` or `++` operator :

```
val xs = List(1, 2, 3)
val ys = List(4, 5, 6)
val zs: List[Int] = xs ++ ys // List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
val as: List[Int] = xs.appendedAll(ys) // List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
val bs: List[Int] = xs.concat(ys) // List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

Comment: `++` is actually a `concat`, not prepend

Comment: @Andronicus yes, that's right, but as I understand xs should be concatenated with yx, is it wrong?

Comment: yes, I'm not saying it's bad, just noted it's a different method, have a great day!;>

Answer (score 1):

```
1. val xs: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
2. val ys: List[Int] = List(4, 5, 6)
3. val zs: List[Int] = xs.appended(ys)
```

The third line is a problem until you have the type declaration. Because when you compile your code compiler is not going to infer the type of the variable zs and it will expect the output of `xs.appended(ys)` to be a List[Int] which is not the case because xs is List[Int] now if you want to add an element in this list you can do `xs.append(1)` or any other integer but you are trying to insert List[Int] which is not Int.

Now when you remove the type declaration from line 3 it compile successfully because now compiler will infer the type of the variable zs and if you will see on REPL it will say the of this variable zs is List[Any].

Now if you want to add list into a list and get a flatten result you can simply use

`val zs: List[Int] = xs ::: ys`

If you will see the scala docs [here](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html)

this is the signature of appended:

```
final def:+[B >: A](elem: B): List[B]
```

**:+ is Alias for appended**

**:++ is Alias for appendedAll**

As we can see from the signature appended function takes a parameter of type B and return List[B] in your case B is Int and you are trying to add List[Int].

I hope it clears why you are getting the compilation error.